# Read AVAudioPcmBuffer audio data as a float[] in C# Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, avaudioengine

I am attempting to read audio data from an `AVAudioPCMBuffer` into an array of `float` values.  The following is an extension method I have created for this purpose:

```
public static float[] ToFloatArray(this AVAudioPcmBuffer pcmBuffer)
{
    if ((pcmBuffer != null) && 
        (pcmBuffer.FloatChannelData != IntPtr.Zero))
    {
        int length = (Convert.ToInt32(pcmBuffer.FrameLength) * 2);
        if (length > 0)
        {
            var data = new float[length];
            Marshal.Copy(pcmBuffer.FloatChannelData, data, 0, length);
            return data;
        }
        else return new float[0];
    }
    else return null;
}
```

The method seems to return data of an appropriate length (8820 samples given a sample rate of 44100), **however the values do not appear to make sense, with many of them being `NaN`**.

Below is a *QuickWatch* on `data` in the above method just after the `Marshal.Copy` operation:

[image: QuickWatch on data output from AVAudioPcmBuffer]

I had intended to use the `float[]` values to create a VU meter, but when monitoring in real time, the values do not seem to change significantly with microphone input, nor do I understand why many values contain *Not a Number* (`NaN`).

I do know that the `AVAudioPcmBuffer` contains valid audio data, as I am sending to a `SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest` via `Append(AVAudioPcmBuffer audioPcmBuffer)`, and the speech recognition is working perfectly.

I have a suspicion that `Marshal.Copy` may be copying the wrong data.  **Can someone confirm this, and/or present the correct way of accessing `float[]` values from an `AVAudioPcmBuffer` within C# Xamarin for iOS?**

Answer (score 0):

[FloatChannelData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiopcmbuffer/1386212-floatchanneldata?language=objc) returns a pointer to float pointers, rather than a single pointer. So you need to dereference the `float **` to get to your `float *`. So, assuming that in your example you are dealing with mono, you would just need to change:

`Marshal.Copy(pcmBuffer.FloatChannelData, data, 0, length)`

to

`Marshal.Copy(pcmBuffer.FloatChannelData[0], data, 0, length)`

Comment: I have attempted to do this, but `FloatChannelData` is of type `IntPtr`, which cannot accept an indexer.  I have updated my code from above to attempt reading as `double` values instead of `float` (as `nfloat` appears to be 64-bit) but the data read still does not appear to be valid audio samples.  Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

[FloatChannelData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiopcmbuffer/1386212-floatchanneldata?language=objc) is pointer to channels, so to get bytes you need to do this -

```
var channels = (IntPtr*)buffer.FloatChannelData.ToPointer();
Marshal.Copy(channels[0], data, 0, length);
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with FloatChannelData, it is utterly impossible to avoid using unsafe code because FloatChannelData is a 2-dimensional float array float[channel][data_per_channel].

You need to wrap your code in a method declared as unsafe and check allow unsafe code in your iOS project.

```
public unsafe float[] ToFloatArray(this AVAudioPcmBuffer pcmBuffer)
{
     if ((pcmBuffer != null) && 
     (pcmBuffer.FloatChannelData != IntPtr.Zero))
     {
        int length = (Convert.ToInt32(pcmBuffer.FrameLength) * 2);
        if (length > 0)
        {
            var data = new float[length];
            float** channelData = (float**)pcmBuffer.FloatChannelData;
            for (int j = 0; j < data.Length; j++)
            {
                data[j] = *(channelData[0] + j);
            }
            return data;
        }
        else return new float[0];
     }
     else return null;
}
```